# Application installation problem

Tags: iphone

I am trying to install applications on my iTouch. But i am facing a problem like each new application is getting installed on previous application and so previous application is getting vanished. :(

Do any body know how to remove this bug. Is there any problem in Profile or Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I add on a version number to my reverse URL Identifier (in target->properties) and use a wildcard provisioning profile.

That way my beta testers can keep old versions of my app for regression testing.

Comment: Please don't use a signature (RF) in your questions/answers. Your name already shows up below your question/answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing the version number doesn't do the trick. It still replaces the older install as the device thinks it's a newer version. (Which is true)

**Changing the ID** makes the device believe it's a different app. That **would do the trick**.

Comment: It should do the trick, but most of the time it doesn't. Xcode has bugs. Lots of them.

Answer (score -1):

New applications replace older applications if and only if their ID is the same. Are you sure you're using unique identifiers for your apps?